# Update content based on server side data changes

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I'm working on a browser game that uses the possibilities of PWA. As a first test, I made an online tic-tac-toe game. After starting a new game the user can enter the email address of a registered other user to invite him. The other player then receives a notification that he can accept a make his first move in the game. The question is now how can I update the data for the first player? It does not have to be in realtime.

- Ajax Polling (probably outdated today)
- Push Notification (required if the user has the game still open?)
- EventSource (usable for multiple users? different games? network usage on mobile?)
- Any other idea?

EDIT: PWA is hosted on a shared virtual webserver without root access
EDIT: Primary targets are mobile devices (limited bandwidth)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested as EventSource. This approach still requires a loop on the webserver who is checking for changes in a database or session. That's not usable for this problem. And a persistent connection is not acceptable for mobile devices.

I found out that the Push API is not tied to notifications. This is defined by the browser implementation. Currently, chrome requires that each push message generates a notification as firefox has a limit of how many push messages can be received without a notification.

So the solution to my problem is solved as i now send a push message from webserver, invoked by a player who made an action.

1. Player 1 selects a field, sends a POST request to webserver to store
   the action
2. Webserver sends a push message to other player with a serialized
   object as payload
3. ServiceWorker of player 2 receives message and parses the payload
4. Parsed payload contains instructions to update the game
5. Game of player 2 sends a GET request to webserver and receives the newest data

Answer (score 0):

If the game is open by both users you can use web-sockets.
Its a tech to keep an open connection between client and server, and the server can manage the game and push messages to the clients by the defined game logic.

[WebSockets Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket)

Edit: It can be used to manage multiple users as well since the server has all connections and can distribute the messages as it needs.

Comment: and what when one player closes the pwa? as i now this will require a script on the server to be running as independet process right? this is currently not possible as i using a simple webhosting.

Comment: in web-sockets when the user closes the app the connection will be closed (even though WS have mechanism to wait for reconnection). and yes, this will require server run a process.